# BiDirectional Sync Provisioning Between SQL CE and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, sql-server-ce

I have a local SQL CE database and I am trying to sync to a remote SQL Server database using the Microsoft Sync Framework.  I have provisioned both the CE and the Server databases, but when I try to Sync, using `SyncOrchestrator`, I get an error `The stored procedure '[tablename_selectchanges]' doesn't exist.`.

When provisioning the local and remote databases, I first enable tracking on the appropriate tables, then do the following:

CE:

```
    var localScopeDescription = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);
    foreach (var table in tables) {
        localScopeDescription.Tables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(table, remoteConnection));
    }

    var localDatabaseConfiguration = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(localConnection, localScopeDescription);
    if (!localDatabaseConfiguration.ScopeExists(scopeName)) {
        localDatabaseConfiguration.ObjectPrefix = "Sync";
        localDatabaseConfiguration.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
        localDatabaseConfiguration.Apply();
    }
```

Server:

```
    var remoteScopeDescription = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);
    foreach (var table in tables) {
        remoteScopeDescription.Tables.Add(SqlCeSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(table, localConnection));
    }

    var remoteDatabaseConfiguration = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(remoteConnection, remoteScopeDescription);
    if (!remoteDatabaseConfiguration.ScopeExists(scopeName)) {
        remoteDatabaseConfiguration.ObjectPrefix = "Sync";
        remoteDatabaseConfiguration.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
        remoteDatabaseConfiguration.SetCreateTrackingTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Create);
        remoteDatabaseConfiguration.SetCreateTriggersDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Create);
        remoteDatabaseConfiguration.SetCreateProceduresDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);

        remoteDatabaseConfiguration.SetPopulateTrackingTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Create);
        remoteDatabaseConfiguration.SetUseBulkProceduresDefault(true);
        remoteDatabaseConfiguration.Apply();
    }
```

If I remove the `SetCreateProceduresDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip)` line, which seems to prevent the creation of this procedure, I get the following error:

> Invalid column name '__sysChangeTxBsn'.
>
> Invalid column name '__sysInsertTxBsn'.
>
> Invalid column name '__sysTrackingContext'.

Am I setting up my provisioning wrong, and if so, how can I fix this?  Or could these errors be caused by something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered [here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/syncdevdiscussions/thread/55d2c3a3-d1e9-422a-a5eb-d66dd7d5ed89/) by JuneT, hopefully this helps someone else who encounters this problem.

My problem was caused by tracking my changes before I added table descriptions to the server, causing the invalid column names.